# LibreOffice Writer Completely Crashes My Computer

Tags: firefox, libreoffice, crash

Computer - Laptop | Dell Latitude E6410 | Memory 3.18 GiB | Processor Intel Core i5 CPU M 520 @ 2.40GHz x4 | Disk 241.9 GB

Operating System | Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 32bit (Left unmodified/as downloaded.) | Downloaded from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop to a flash drive then burned to a rewritable DVD for installation, the latter of which I still possess.

For reasons unknown to me, LibreOffice Writer crashes almost every time I try to use it. I do not believe anything I am doing with it is causing it to crash as I tried using it in a diverse number of ways (plain text, images, tables, turning off spell check, copy and pasting different things to it, and so on), with nothing so far being longer than three pages. It even crashes when it is the only thing running on my computer beyond the operating system. Every time it crashes it completely freezes almost everything: the mouse pointer will still move but will not click, I can hear the sound from any media I have open, and I can force the computer to turn off by holding down the power button a few seconds, but that is it – I cannot even move to a different window or program.

What should I do to try to remedy this problem? Bear in mind that I am new to Ubuntu and know practically nothing about it beyond viewing the internet with Firefox. Please bear this in mind when responding.

Comment: Is this installation old or new; do you have any data built up or can you just reinstall easily?

Answer (score 0):

[Bug #1495097](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1495097) is about LibreOffice crashes in Ubuntu 14.04 due to shortcomings in the libhunspell-1.3-0 package. The bug has just been fixed, and hopefully also your problem will be gone once you have installed version 1.3.2-6ubuntu2.1 of the package from trusty-proposed.